# Access Google Earth Engine via Jupyter using the Javascript API

Tags: javascript, jupyter-lab, google-earth-engine

I'm very new to Googles Earth Engine and learned how to use the Javascript API. However, I recently found, one can access Earth Engine via Jupyter using the Python API. Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to use Jupyter and Javascript? There are Javascript Kernels that can be installed for Jupyter so I thought this might be possible. 
But I did not find anything about it.
Has anyone tried (and succeeded) yet?

Comment: No, outside of the Javascript Code Editor, you can access GEE only through the python API.

Comment: Have you looked into using NodeJS within Jupyter Notebooks like this [article](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/nodebooks-node-js-data-science-notebooks-aa140bea21ba) and [install the EE javascript library using NPM](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/npm_install)?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try that! Thanks!

Comment: @kel So, I installed a Javascript Kernel on Jupyter Lab and the EE javascript library. However, it is required to set up [Authentication Credentials](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/npm_install#setting-up-authentication-credentials) to access GEE. But these seem to be set up to  to grant clients an access via an app, and not for a private user, so I'm stuck here.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you will need to set up a project in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), get the service account whitelisted, and set up credentials to authenticate. The Earth Engine team has [steps documented](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/service_account) on how to do this.